# Prevent stops application with NSStream in polling mode

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, timeout, nsstream, blocked

I have implemented a client-server transferring from Windows desktop application to iPhone App. I transfer data using NSStream in polling mode (synchronous).

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)urlStr, portNo, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

All works fine, but when I attempt to connect an inexistent server or a disconnected server or the port number/ip address is wrong, the WRITE method of NSOutputStream object, stops the application execution.

```
const uint8_t *str = (uint8_t *) [strRichiesta cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[outputStream write:str maxLength:strlen((char*)str)];
```

Is it possible to manage the method by inserting timeout control?
If yes, how can I do?

I think that the same problem occurs also with READ method of NSInputStream object.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `NSStream`s' `streamStatus` and `streamError` functions before trying to use them for reading and writing.  See Apple's [NSStream Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001981-BBCCEDID) for more info.

This also may help: [Setting Up Socket Streams](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI)

**EDIT:
NSStreamStatus values:**

```
typedef enum {
    NSStreamStatusNotOpen = 0,
    NSStreamStatusOpening = 1,
    NSStreamStatusOpen = 2,
    NSStreamStatusReading = 3,
    NSStreamStatusWriting = 4,
    NSStreamStatusAtEnd = 5,
    NSStreamStatusClosed = 6,
    NSStreamStatusError = 7
};
```

You will have to wait until the status is Open before using it.  It may several seconds (maybe even 30 sec) for a bad URL to resolve to status Error.

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried... no difference. In all cases streamStatus=1 and streamError=empty string.

Comment: Yeah, streamStatus of 1 means its not ready to use. See my edit for more info.